# How to view music files in micro SD in windows7

Tags: windows-7, micro-sd-card

I have a O2 Micro SD SCSI card with music files on it. I am able to use it in my car audio system. But cannot read it in my windows 7 PC. I can see the GPS map folders but not the music folders. How to see the music files in my PC.? The file system in the Micro SD is FAT 32

Comment: If you check with a Linux program such as GParted, does the card have multiple partitions?

Comment: From what I saw on google, these file extensions belong to map files of a car navigation system. Are you sure this is music?

Comment: @Satoh This folder is a map file folder and the rest of the folders contain music files which I am not able to see..

Answer (score -1):

I used the winhex software to read the files.http://winhex.com/winhex/ It is free and can be used to recover the data in SD cards.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about this software? (e.g., what it does, if it's free, how to use it.)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Simon. This is a problem encountered by my colleague in my office. Now he downloaded this software and used it for opening the files.